What is the correct Sample Space?
Original Question:
We choose 3 books from a set of
4 distinct (distinguishable) and 2 indistinct (indistinguishable) books.
Each set of 3 books is equally likely.
Let event E = our choice does not include both indistinct books.

What is P(E)?

Answer Calculation:
Case 1: (No indistinct books): Select 3 books from 4 distinct books, which gives 4 ways.
Case 2: (Exactly 1 indistinct book): Select 1 indistinct book and 2 distinct books, which gives 6 ways.
Case 3: (Both indistinct books): Select both indistinct books and 1 distinct book, which gives 4 ways
But if we forget 2 books are indistinct, total number of ways 3 books can select which gives 20
My Question:
What is the correct P(E) from these two? why?
P(E) = (case 1 + case 2) / (case 1+ case2+ case 3) = 10/14
P(E) = (case 1 + case 2) / 20 = 10/20

I think the easiest approach is to work backwards.  The Event $E^c$ is "you do select both indistinct books.  There are $4$ possible selections which achieve that, as you need only choose one distinct book to complete your selection. As there are $\binom 63=20$ equally probable ways to choose $3$ books out of the $6$ with no restrictions, the answer is $$P(E^c)=\frac 4{20}=\frac 15\implies P(E)=1-P(E^c)=\frac 45$$
which matches neither of your results.
On review:  your first approach is correct but your arithmetic is not.  In case $2$, wherein I wish to choose exactly $1$ indistinct book and exactly $2$ distinct books, there are $2$ ways to choose the indistinct book and $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose the distinct ones, so there are $2\times 6=12$ ways all in all.  Your case $1$ calculation is correct, making the answer $$P(E)=\frac {4+12}{20}=\frac {16}{20}=\frac 45$$
which matches the method I sketched.
I think the confusion lies in the selection of the "indistinct" book.  You might object to my claim that there are $2$ ways to choose that, as there are two indistinct books.  After all, there's no way to know which of the two I chose.  But for counting purposes, it is helpful to regard the "indistinct" books as two, as if the books were $A,B,C,D, E_1, E_2$. This fits the "real world interpretation", as, even if you happen to own two copies of some book, there is no question that they are two physically distinct books. If you insist on counting them as if they were truly indistinguishable, then you must say that the probability of choosing one of the $E's$ initially is twice the probability of choosing any of $A,B,C,D$.  The same "sample space confusion" arises when, say, we consider tossing a pair of dice.  If you regard the two ordered pairs of tosses $(1,2), (2,1)$ as indistinguishable then you have to say that the unordered pair $\{1,2\}$ is twice as probable as $\{1,1\}$, say.  But if we agree to consider them as different, even though the end results are indistinguishable, then you can treat them as equi-probable, which makes the arithmetic simpler.
For intuition, I suggest simulating the process (interpreting "indistinct" in either of the ways I proposed).  Your second proposed solution is far too small, as a simulation should reveal.

I voted for this answer because I think it is the most reasonable interpretation of the question. But the question, in fact, is horribly written. Why on Earth would they ask about four "distinguishable" and two "indistinguishable" books instead of, say, four math books and two physics books? It seems to be a question written by someone more interested in torturing helpless students than actually doing math.

@DavidK  I mean, it just invites confusion.

@DavidK  I like the roll of two dice example.  It's clear that somebody might want to say that $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are the same.  Who cares which dice came up what?  But treating them as different makes life so much easier.

Take a marker and mark a small dot on the corner of one of the indistinguishable books. Now you have six books, all distinguishable.

That answer is only partially a joke. The point is that this wording of the question is bad enough to deserve such an answer.
The real answer, of course, is that
$$ P(E) = (\text{case }1 + \text{case }2) /
 (\text{case }1 + \text{case }2 + \text{case }3) $$
because case $1$, case $2$, and case $3$ cover all possible outcomes.
But in order to make the formula work, you need to count the outcomes in case $1$, case $2$, and case $3$ so that they're all equally likely.
The question says, "Each set of 3 books is equally likely," but it also talks about indistinguishable books, which we typically don't built sets from.
This is causing you some trouble identifying equally likely outcomes.
If the question stated that you had a multiset of books
$\{a, b, c, d, i, i\}$, where the two $i$s are the "indistinguishable" books,
and if it stated that every multiset of size three was equally likely, then there would be $14$ equally likely outcomes including multisets such as
$\{a, b, c\}$, $\{a, b, i\}$, and $\{a, i, i\}$.
But there is no mathematical set of three objects identified $\{a, i, i\}$.
Viewed as a mathematical set, $\{a, i, i\}$ contains only two elements, $a$ and $i$. The number of times $i$ is listed is irrelevant.
So either the two "indistinguishable" books are actually sufficiently distinct that they can count as two elements of a set, or the probability of having "both" indistinguishable books in a set is zero, or we're not actually talking about mathematical sets.
My answer would be that in the absence of any special information stating otherwise, we should treat the six books the same as we would treat six balls in an urn whose colors are, say, one each red, blue, white, and green and two yellow. A sample space for choosing three balls from the urn has $20$ equally likely outcomes in which we may put distinct numbers on the two yellow balls in order to conveniently list the outcomes.
It is possible to set up a selection process so that there are $14$ equally likely outcomes, but this requires more than just erasing any identifying marks on the indistinguishable books. That's why I would reject such an answer.
On the other hand, I wouldn't trust someone who writes a question like this to give a good answer to it.
In other words, I would not bet on what the answer key will say.
If this is a question you must answer for homework, I recommend to ask for clarification of the meaning of a "set of three books" if you can,
and whether it is not true that if you first line up all the books on a shelf, you are equally likely to choose the first three books, the first, second, and fifth book, or the first, second, and sixth book.
If you do not have to do this question for homework and you are not likely to see such a question on an exam, I would recommend to ignore the question and work on the next one, which hopefully will be better written.

Alternative approach
Given any set $~E,~$ with a finite number of elements, let $~| ~E ~|~$ denote the number of elements in the set $~E.$
Assume that there are $~6~$ distinct books that are labeled 
Book-1, Book-2, Book-3, Book-4, Book-5, Book-6.
Let the set $~S~$ denote the set of all equally likely ways of choosing any $~3~$ books, from the $~6~$ distinguishable books.
Then
$$| ~S ~| = \binom{6}{3} = 20.$$
Let the set $~T~$ denote the subset of $~S~$ where the $~3~$ selected books include both Book-5 and Book-6.
Then
$$| ~T ~| = \binom{2}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} = 4.$$
That is, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{2}~$ ways of selecting $~2~$ books from $~\{ ~\text{Book-5}, ~\text{Book-6} ~\},~$ and  $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1}~$ ways of selecting $~1~$ book from $~\{ ~\text{Book-1}, ~\text{Book-2} ~ ~\text{Book-3}, ~\text{Book-4} ~\}.$
Therefore, if you assume that all $~6~$ books are distinguishable, then the desired computation is
$$ \frac{| ~S ~| - |~ T ~|}{| ~S ~|} = \frac{20 - 4}{20} = \frac{16}{20} = \frac{4}{5}. \tag1 $$
Note that the computation in (1) above critically depends on the fact that all elements in the set $~S~$ are equally likely.

$~\underline{\text{Where You Went Wrong}}$

Case 2: (Exactly 1 indistinct book): Select 1 indistinct book and 2 distinct books, which gives 6 ways.

You can assume, without loss of generality, that Book-5 and Book-6 each have their labels covered by a book cover, so that Book-5 and Book-6 are now indistinguishable, while the other $~4~$ books remain distinguishable.
Then, the problem with your approach is that if you compare the $~6~$ ways represented by Case 2 against the $~8~$ ways represented by
$~[ ~\text{Case 1} ~+ ~\text{Case 3} ~],~$ you see that each of the $~6~$ ways represented by Case 2 are twice as likely as each of the
$~8~$ ways represented by $~[ ~\text{Case 1} ~+ ~\text{Case 3} ~].$
That is, the $~6~$ ways represented by Case 2 are actually represented by $~12~$ of the equally likely elements in set $~S.$
